What should I back transform beta coefficients when my dependent variable is fractionally exponentiated in R
I have this mixed effects regression model. To create a normal distribution in continuous scale  dependent variable, I fractionally exponentiated it:
TB_fract <- TB ^ (1/1.4)

My following model is then as such where period represents integer values of time and MRN represents individual subjects:
lme4::lmer(TB_fract ~ Surg_group_fact + (1 + period|MRN), data = full_patient_data_2, na.action = na.omit)

My output is such. time_below_sqrt is the DV representation of TB_fract:


I clearly have negative beta estimates which won't allow to transform to the power of 1.4. How do I then interpret these results if my DV is a fractional value of the original value with negative beta coefficients?

Let's turn the question around: What is the rationale for such a complicated transformation?

Well, my TB variable was not passing normalcy tests and was slightly right tailed. Log or squared transformations were too great of shifts in the data and just turned a right tail into a left tail. The exponentiation to the power of 1.4 seemed to get the data into a normal distribution. Should I not have done this? Would you have left the dependent variable as is and performed the analysis? I always assumed you should have your DV normally distributed if you're using types of linear regression.

In the comments, it was clarified $y^{\frac{1}{1.4}}$ was used due to skew in the outcome. Based on that, please note:

There is no need for the outcome, nor any other variable in your data to follow a normal distribution. The assumption in linear models regards the error term, which in practice, you can evaluate by inspecting the residuals of your model. It is possible that even though your outcome is not approximately normal, after taking into account all the effects of the explanatory variable, the remainder is. Valid inference with your model only depends on the latter.
If the residuals are still problematically deviating from a normal distribution, there are other candidate distributions you could use, like the lognormal, or gamma. In your code, just change lme4::lmer(...) to lme4::glmer(..., family = Gamma(link = "log"), for example.
If you still opt to use a normal linear mixed model and transform the outcome, I have two suggestions:

Use something a little easier to interpret, like $y^\frac{1}{1.4} \approx y^{0.5} = \sqrt{y}$... It may not work as well, but is a lot easier to interpret.
Consider the bias introduced through the retransformation problem. With a log-transformation, you can use Duan's smearing estimator... With a fractional transformation, I'm not sure how to do it.




As for how to transform back to the original scale, the idea is to first add all relevant coefficients on the scale of the model, and then transform the resulting number back using the inverse of the transformation used:
# Outcome for the reference group
14.2235 ^ (1.4)
# 41.13477

# Outcome for the factAPW group
(14.2235 + 5.9138) ^ (1.4)
# 66.92706

From the part of the output you have shown, this will not be a problem for any of the estimates, because the intercept should also be added, and so none will be below zero.

There are other problems still with your model output, like the perfect negative correlation between the random intercept and slope, but that has already been discussed elsewhere (e.g., here).
